# AngularJS ngRepeat loop variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following code:

```
 $scope.links = { 
            home: {text:'Home', link:'#'},
            about: {text:'Contact', link:'#'},
            handeMade: {text:'Contact', link:'#'},
            shirts: {text:'Contact', link:'#'},
            design: {text:'Contact', link:'#'},
            photography: {text:'Contact', link:'#'},
            blog: {text:'Contact', link:'#'},
            contact: {text:'Contact', link:'#'}
        }
```

I want to loop the variable inside the scope links using the directive ngRepeat to get the text and the link of each object, is it possible to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: yes. try to experiment.

Comment: @Nabila that is very basic stuff, just have a look at the [ngRepeat docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) and you'll sort that out.

Comment: -1 no research effort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See how this works:

```
<div ng-repeat="link in links track by $index">
    <p>Text: {{link.text}}</p>
    <p>Link: {{link.link}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,value) in links">
  <div ng-repeat="(k,v) in value">
     <p>Text: {{k.text}}</p>
     <p>Link: {{k.link}}</p>
   </div>
</div>
```